# If A is a projection matrix then A' is also a projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, projection-matrices

Is this correct? One projects to the column space of A while the other to the row space of A?

Comment: KEY PROPERTY: $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$. In particular $(A^2)^T=(AA)^T=A^TA^T=(A^T)^2$.

Answer (score 2):

I presume that by $A'$ you mean $A^\top$, the transpose of $A$. Do you know that projection matrices (projecting orthogonally onto their range or column space) are characterized in general by the two criteria 
$$A^2=A \qquad\text{and}\qquad A=A^\top?$$
If so, you only need to check that $A^\top$ satisfies these criteria if (and only if) $A$ does. And, of course, it's obvious since $A^\top=A$.

For non-orthogonal projections, the criterion is merely $A^2=A$, and so you once again must check that one condition for $A^\top$, which is still easy.

Comment: Yes, but if $A=A^T$ (orthogonal projection) then everything is trivial. Probably the OP refers to non-orthogonal projection, which satisfy $A^2=A$ only.

Comment: Yeah, I was about to edit.

Comment: Yes, A is not necessarily orthogonal. So $A^T$ is not necessarily A but I am asking if it is still a projector.

Comment: Right, I addressed that. If $A^2=A$, then it's immediate that $(A^\top)^2 = A^\top$ as well. See Giuseppe's comment.

Comment: Thanks. I erased my answer. Sorry, unfamiliar with the rules.